# In Redis Is there a way to delete a key using the Redis api

Tags: redis

We are trying to automate some processes and unfortunately no one here know enough about Redis API to help out.  We can doing this using the GUI client but would like to use Redi API to delete a key in a database.
I could not find any examples or references that getting me going through this.  I am hoping someone may have some experience with the API that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the Redis api, but you could do that using `Lua script`. It goes like this

```lua
eval "return redis.pcall('del', '<key>')" 0
```

This [doc](https://redis.io/commands/eval) might be of some help.

Also, it will be great if you could mention the api client you are using to better understand your scenario.

Comment: No client.  Using either curl or PowerShell to send an Post to the Redis API to perform the delete.

Comment: Could you post that here, sanitized